# Find a route in a database

Tags: sql, t-sql

Is there a way to find the shortest route between a starting point (Tablename) and a column in another Tablename.

I am not looking for a way to propagate the keys between 2 tables, this is explained many times on te web. This is a complex database, it has so much relations and tables that its merely impossible to find the shortest route by hand. I am thinking there must be a way to find the shortest route between 2 points.

I have found all kinds of code, but all look for direct relations and stop there. Is my question even posible?

Comment: This is a very complex problem. Is the shortest route always the right route? Probably not. What do you do if you can go from TableA to TableZ through TableX or through TableY? So, "Is my question even posible?" Perhaps, but if you want to use SQL only, it's going to be hellish. Either way, this question is too broad as it stands.

Comment: @HoneyBadger Say theres Point a and b where a is a table and b a column in a table, between them there can be many routes. Via table k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, etc. the column name is in many tables, but i need to find the one that is the shortest from point a. I don't know howto explain is clearer. I had imagined the database must somehow know all this because the relations exist, from a to k to l to o to q to r for example and from a to k to l to r for example, so the last one would be the shortest route. Is this any clearer? English is not my first language.

Comment: Your question was clear enough, but there is no easy answer. If you really need this, you'll have to make a start yourself. If you run into issues during the progress you can always come back here with a more specific question. You should probably start by enumerating all the relationships, once you have those finding the shortest route might not be that hard. Best of luck!

Comment: Addition to the previous comment i made, in all cases i know the starting table and the ending table.column.

Comment: There is no *out-of-the-box* tool for this, I'm afraid... If all relations are explicitly existing as FK constraints, this will lead to some kind of recursive search. This can be done, but there are many obstacles. In *real-life* database we often see missing keys, keys via materialized views, multi-column keys and so on...

Comment: Once I wrote a [simple DDL to JSON](https://gist.github.com/ceving/c6df834bbf5ec815becd) converter. It shows also the references. The JSON can be searched with [Jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/). This might be a starting point for your project.

Comment: @ceving Thanks for your reply, i have looked over your project but i dont seem to grasp howto work it out unfortunately. I have however started designing something from scratch in native SQL. If i need more help i will post a new post with some code and a more straight forward question.